# Magento CVV What is this help link not works

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, credit-card

In the magento (ver 1.9) Checkout Payment Information tab, Clicking on CVV "What is this" help link not working.

Help image is exist there. a tag has# link. No errors are displayed.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you add URL for your setup?

Comment: Sorry It is my company's confidential server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do to debug the issue.
When you click on "What's this" link, it calls a function in **skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js**

```
initWhatIsCvvListeners: function(){
    $$('.cvv-what-is-this').each(function(element){
        Event.observe(element, 'click', toggleToolTip);
    });
}
```

Here it checks for click on `cvv-what-is-this` class element. The class is added to "What's this" link in **app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\YOUR_TEMPLATE\template\payment\form\ccsave.phtml**

```
<a href="#" class="cvv-what-is-this"><?php echo $this->__('What is this?') ?></a>
```

When clicked on "What's this" it will call function `toggleToolTip` added in **app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\YOUR_TEMPLATE\template\checkout\onepage\payment.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function toggleToolTip(event){
        if($('payment-tool-tip')){
            $('payment-tool-tip').setStyle({
                top: (Event.pointerY(event)-560)+'px'//,
                //left: (Event.pointerX(event)+100)+'px'
            })
            $('payment-tool-tip').toggle();
        }
        Event.stop(event);
    }
    if($('payment-tool-tip-close')){
        Event.observe($('payment-tool-tip-close'), 'click', toggleToolTip);
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

This will toggle element with class `payment-tool-tip`. This element contains your CVV images.

```
<div class="tool-tip" id="payment-tool-tip" style="display:none;">
    <div class="btn-close"><a href="#" id="payment-tool-tip-close" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a></div>
    <div class="tool-tip-content"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/cvv.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference') ?>" /></div>
</div>
```

Make sure you have all these files added in your theme with required data.  You can refer to **RWD** theme.